# Selecting Random row from a table using DOM and ejs

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table, ejs

Here is my code -

```
<tbody class = "tbody">
    <% for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { %>
    <tr id="tr">
        <th><%= i + 1 %></th>
        <th><%= users[i].name %></th>
        <th><%= users[i].email %></th>
        <th><%= users[i].age %></th>
        <th><%= users[i].address %></th>
        <th><button class="update" data-id=<%= users[i]._id %>><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button>         </th>
        <th><button class="delete" data-id=<%= users[i]._id %>><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button></th>
    </tr>
    <%}%>   
</tbody>

const deleteButton = document.querySelector(".delete")
    
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let id = deleteButton.getAttribute("data-id")
    alert("ok")
    console.log(id)
})
```

what I want is when I click in any delete icon the alert should pop up but
when I click in the delete icon it works only for the first one. Nothing happens when I click the rest of them.

I don't know how to do it!

Comment: Because [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) only return the **first** element that match the CSS selector, so only the first button is bound to the event listener.

Comment: Thanks to the solution

Answer (score 0):

You should use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all elements with that selector (class in this case)

Also you need add an event to each of them

I used [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind button as a parameter here, but you can use another way that you want, is just an example.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");

function onButtonClick(button, ev) {
    const id = button.getAttribute("data-id");
    button.classList.toggle("deleted-example");
    console.log({ id });
}

Array.from(buttons).forEach(button => {
    // use bind to bind button parameter
    button.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick.bind(null, button), true);
});
```

```css
.deleted-example {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="delete" data-id="1">delete 1</div>
    <div class="delete" data-id="2">delete 2</div>
    <div class="delete" data-id="3">delete 3</div>
    <div class="delete" data-id="4">delete 4</div>
</div>
```